# Youtube data API: Total count of videos from youtube search request is incorrect

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

When I'm sending https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UCF80293azxnDAdbOa7fFKfw&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics

I'm getting

```
videoCount: "28"
```

But when I'm sending https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=UCF80293azxnDAdbOa7fFKfw&maxResults=50&part=snippet&q&type=video

with params:

```
channelId: UCF80293azxnDAdbOa7fFKfw
maxResults: 50
part: snippet
q: 
type: video
```

I'm getting

```
totalResults: 40
```

Why results are different? Both requests are related to videos of specific channel.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem.  You're already over your daily limit for requests.

Comment: Well, you need to use API key or Authentication to make requests to youtube API. I didn't put here my API key. Without authentication I'm getting this error message: "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." I think you meant this. With API key request is successful.

Comment: This may be a bug, I have replicated your issue but when I counted the `channelID` it matches the first query. Try filling a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) then post the link here for the benefit of the community.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120461456